# how does `flat_map` affect my code?

Tags: rust

I have been working on the following code for my whole day,([here](http://is.gd/xA14n7) is the playpen)

```
/// The rule that moves state from one to another.
///
/// `S` - the type parameter of state.
///
/// `T` - the type parameter of input symbol.
#[deriving(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct Rule<S, T> {
  pub state: S,
  pub symbol: Option<T>,
  pub next_state: S
}

impl<S: PartialEq, T: PartialEq> Rule<S, T> {
  /// determine whether the rule applies to the given state and symbol
  pub fn apply_to(&self, state: &S, symbol: &Option<T>) -> bool {
    self.state == *state && self.symbol == *symbol
  }
}

/// The transition relation in NFA,
/// containing all the rules needed by the NFA.
pub struct NFATransitions<S, T> {
  pub rules: HashSet<Rule<S, T>>
}

impl<S: Eq + Hash + Clone, T: Eq + Hash> NFATransitions<S, T> {

  pub fn next_states(&self, states: &HashSet<S>, symbol: &Option<T>) -> HashSet<S> {
    states.iter().flat_map(|state| {
      // error goes here: borrowed value does not live long enough
      self.next_states_for(state, symbol).iter().map(|s| s.clone())
    }).collect()

    // Howover, the following code which have the same behavior can compile

    // let mut result = HashSet::new();
    // for state in states.iter() {
    //   result.extend(self.next_states_for(state, symbol).iter().map(|s| s.clone()));
    // }
    //
    // result
  }

  /// get the next state for the given state and symbol
  fn next_states_for(&self, state: &S, symbol: &Option<T>) -> HashSet<S> {
    self.rules.iter().filter_map(|rule| {
      if rule.apply_to(state, symbol) { Some(rule.next_state.clone()) } else { None }
    }).collect()
  }
}
```

The code is just a wrapper of a hashset used for the nfa transition rules.(It's not what I'm concerned)

The `flat_map` is where I got compile error.
It seems strange to me, as the commented lines, which I think have same behavior as the `flat_map`, can do well.

I cannot figure out how the `error: borrowed value does not live long enough` error comes out.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I conjecture the lifetime of the result of the closure is too short because the result of `next_states_for` is a temporary.

Comment: Can you provide a playpen link with the source/implementation of Rule too?

Comment: @delnan then, do you get any clues about this? after all, it seems to be a common use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the `iter()`, this is tied to the lifetime of the result of `next_states_for()`, and is an iterator of `&`-pointers.

Since `next_states_for()` already clones stuff for you, `into_iter()` is what you want, which moves the items out of the collection.

```
  pub fn next_states(&self, states: &HashSet<S>, symbol: &Option<T>) -> HashSet<S> {
    states.iter().flat_map(|state| {
      // error goes here: borrowed value does not live long enough
      self.next_states_for(state, symbol).into_iter()
    }).collect()
  }
```

The closure captures by reference, which is why this is different from the for loop.